# "Sedgefield Yellow" and "Mallowflier"

Tags: british-english, slang, understanding

the text is from a play called The River. characters are talking about fishing. What are "Black Bomber", "Sedgefield Yellow" and "Mallowflier" referring to? are the same things? my question is about what kind of droppers are they talking about?
The black bomber is a kind of fishing reel?!

THE WOMAN. I changed to a Black Bomber with three
droppers.

THE MAN. You had three droppers?!
<…>

THE WOMAN. Sedgefield Yellow, a Black Gnat, and a…

BOTH. Mallowflier.

Comment: My guess is that they are fishing flies (artificial insects used to catch insect-eating fish). https://www.sportfish.co.uk/fly-fishing-tackle/fly-fishing-flies.html

Comment: This is something to answer with Google. It has nothing to do with English grammar.

Comment: @Astralbee even though I knew what I was looking for I found choosing the right search terms quite hard so although you have a point I think in this case it was understandable that the OP posted here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two of those terms are sorts of fishing fly: Black Bomber and Black Gnat. A dropper is a piece of extra line enabling you to attach more than one fly to your line so increasing the chances of catching a fish. The other two, Sedgefield Yellow and Mallowflier, do not seem to be common sorts of fly.

You can see pictures of the two which are flies by putting Black Bomber Fly into your favourite search engine.